# Can't access import.io's new web extractor/dashboard

Tags: import.io

I'm reading through this articles:

- https://www.import.io/post/our-biggest-update-ever/
- http://importio.desk.com/customer/en/portal/articles/2402346-import-io-product-list

First one says:

> If you log into Import.io using a web browser you will see the new platform but if you log into Import.io using the desktop application you will see the old platform.

Well, no. If I log in with a browser I see the old platform.

Second article states:

> My Data/Dashboard
>   http://dash.import.io

This just renders a blank page.

Seems like I am not able to access the new platform?
I am authenticated via Github using Firefox 38.1.0.

EDIT:
Before you downvote:

https://www.import.io/help/community

SO is listed as an official community support channel

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow is a programming community. This question will be more suited to their facebook group (https://www.facebook.com/groups/333804556787487/567946190039988/) or their new forum (http://community.import.io/).

But it seems that the page is not compatible with Firefox 38.X. Right now we're only supporting the last version of Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Comment: https://www.import.io/help/community/ SO is listed as an official community support channel

Comment: For technical questions, probably StackOverflow is not the audience you're trying to reach with that question!

Comment: It is a technical question.

Comment: Ok, verified. http://dash.import.io is not working right now for FF 38.X, but it is working for the last stable version (FF46).